# Guardar ciertas propiedades de un objeto "A" a un nuevo objeto "B" vacio

Tags: javascript, ajax, web

Mediante una petición Hxr obtengo datos de un archivo Json y lo parseo a un objeto Javascript declarado como `datos`, la idea era utilizar este objeto para rellenar diferentes `select` mediante un ciclo for  `for(let item of datos){}` el caso es que en alguno de esos `select` algunos elementos `option` se repiten por ende decidí hacer una condición `if(...in...){}` para poder guardar las propiedades que no se repitan en un nuevo objeto declarado como `let result = {}`, una vez "rellenado" este ultimo, lo utilizaría para completar el `select` antes mencionado.
Cabe destacar que soy nuevo en Javascript, por ende nose si estoy bien enfocado en mi código, ya sea en términos de sintaxis, semántica e inclusive rendimiento, aclaro esto porque al estar empezando con este lenguaje ya me gustaría poder contar con buenas practicas. A continuacion dejo el codigo que describo junto con parte del archivo Json(es muy extenso para colocarlo todo).

```js
[
    {
        "bloque":"Condiciones materiales",
        "dimension":"Vivienda",
        "indicador":"Calidad de los materiales - piso",
        "encabezado":["Suficiente","Parcial","Insuficiente"],
        "col":["pisosufi","pisopar","pisoinsu"]
    },
        {
        "bloque":"Condiciones materiales",
        "dimension":"Ingreso",
        "indicador":"Mediana IPCF",
        "encabezado":["Total","Mujeres","Varones"],
        "col":["medianaipcfto","medianaipcfmu","medianaipcfva"]
    },
    {
        "bloque":"Condiciones materiales",
        "dimension":"Ingreso",
        "indicador":"Brecha por sexo - media de IPCF",
        "encabezado":["Brecha por sexo - media de IPCF"],
        "col":["sexipcf"]
    },
        {
        "bloque":"Condiciones materiales",
        "dimension":"Empleo",
        "indicador":"Brecha por sexo - Jovenes NI ",
        "encabezado":["Brecha por sexo - Jovenes NI "],
        "col":["sexni"]
    }
]

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",carga);
function carga(){
  const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("GET", "bd.json", true);
  xhttp.send();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      let datos = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      //console.log(datos);
      //document.querySelector("#campo").value = this.responseText;
      let bloque = document.querySelector("#bloque");
      let result = {};
      for(let item of datos){
        if (!(item.dimension in result)){
            result = item.dimension;
            console.log(result);
        }
      }
    }
  };
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <br><br><br>
        <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="bloque"></select>
        <br><br>
        <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="dimension"></select>
        <br><br>
        <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="indicador"></select>
      <br><br><br>

<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="res">

  </tbody>
</table>
<p id="prueba"> </p>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-IDwe1+LCz02ROU9k972gdyvl+AESN10+x7tBKgc9I5HFtuNz0wWnPclzo6p9vxnk" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="functions.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo así:

```js
const datos = [
    {
        "bloque":"Condiciones materiales",
        "dimension":"Vivienda",
        "indicador":"Calidad de los materiales - piso",
        "encabezado":["Suficiente","Parcial","Insuficiente"],
        "col":["pisosufi","pisopar","pisoinsu"]
    },
        {
        "bloque":"Condiciones materiales",
        "dimension":"Ingreso",
        "indicador":"Mediana IPCF",
        "encabezado":["Total","Mujeres","Varones"],
        "col":["medianaipcfto","medianaipcfmu","medianaipcfva"]
    },
    {
        "bloque":"Condiciones materiales",
        "dimension":"Ingreso",
        "indicador":"Brecha por sexo - media de IPCF",
        "encabezado":["Brecha por sexo - media de IPCF"],
        "col":["sexipcf"]
    },
        {
        "bloque":"Condiciones materiales",
        "dimension":"Empleo",
        "indicador":"Brecha por sexo - Jovenes NI ",
        "encabezado":["Brecha por sexo - Jovenes NI "],
        "col":["sexni"]
    }
]
    
//let datos = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
const bloques = [...new Set(datos.map(dato => dato.bloque))];
const dimensiones = [...new Set(datos.map(dato => dato.dimension))];
const indicadores = [...new Set(datos.map(dato => dato.indicador))];

console.log({bloques, dimensiones, indicadores});
```

Ahi obtienes los bloques, dimensiones e indicadores sin repetir.

Ya con esos datos puedes llenar los select.

Comment: para complementar tu respuesta y que sea mas entendible para un principiante en Js como es mi caso, investigue sobre las funciones flecha ```=>```  y también sobre el método ```map()``` y aquí coloco un fragmento del código sin compactar la función, al menos como ejemplo ```const bloques = [...new Set(datos.map(function(dato){
 return dato.bloque;   
}))];``` @Pipe